# Assign names to data frame with as.data.frame function

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to convert a matrix into data frame, and assign the names in one line.

As I used `?as.data.frame` there is a parameter called `col.names` which doesn't seem to work for me, am I doing something wrong?

```
as.data.frame(matrix(c(1:4), nrow=2), col.names=c("a","b"))
```

Output:

```
   V1 V2  
1  1  3  
2  2  4
```

Expected Output:

```
   a  b  
1  1  3  
2  2  4
```

I know I can assign it later with `colnames(matrix) = c("a,"b), but i am just wondering if it is possible to do it in one line. (

Answer (score 11):

We can use `dimnames` argument in `matrix` and this will return with the column names as such when converting to `data.frame`

```
as.data.frame(matrix(1:4, nrow=2, dimnames = list(NULL, c("a", "b"))))
#  a b
#1 1 3
#2 2 4
```

while in the OP's code, the `matrix` output didn't have any column names, so `as.data.frame` creates column names as 'V1', 'V2' by default.  The `col.names` argument is not `as.data.frame` for `class` `matrix`, so it didn't have any effect

If we quote the documentation of `?as.data.frame`

> S3 method for class 'matrix'
>
> as.data.frame(x, row.names = NULL, optional = FALSE, ...,
>                 stringsAsFactors = default.stringsAsFactors())

Comment: What do you mean  is not `as.data.frame`? So it belongs to another function?

Thanks though, it was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @SaulGarcia  If you check the documentation of `?as.data.frame` `## S3 method for class 'matrix'
as.data.frame(x, row.names = NULL, optional = FALSE, ...,
              stringsAsFactors = default.stringsAsFactors())`

Comment: Yes, this is under `Usage`, then below that, there is a section called `Arguments`, that is where I found `col.names` but maybe it means something else. Thank you @akrun

Comment: @SaulGarcia  It has different methods.  For `list`, you can pass the col.names, but here you have a `matrix`

Comment: Yes, these are those tiny little things which make us all love to code in R.

Comment: In everyday language: 1. Design flaw. 2. Poor documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I know that it's an old question, but is:

`as.data.frame %>% colnames<-("Name here")` not also a solution in 'one line' as the original poster wanted, but just with pipes?

All the best,
Patrick

Comment: `setNames()` is often nicer in a pipeline than `colnames<-()`. E.g., `mat %>% as.data.frame() %>% setNames(c("a", "b"))`.

Comment: Good catch, I'll try to save this one in my head instead ;-)